# Rails 4 pg_search - multisearchable Issue

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, pg-search, trigram

I'm using the pg_search gem for Rails (Ruby 2.1.1, Rails 4.1.4) and trying to implement a global multisearch for some of my models but I keep getting

`PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: text % unknown`

when I run the multisearch command.

Here are my models:

```
# name    :text
class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :expression
  multisearchable against: :name
end

# type    :text
class Expression < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal
  multisearchable against: :type
end
```

My search query is then something like `Happy Tiger`

When I run `PgSearch.multisearch("Happy Tiger")` though, I get that above error.

I also have an initializer that tells PgSearch to use `trigram`

Any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

I realized I needed to install trigram in postgres :P